# How to use a select to return one row within a UDF

Tags: mysql

I have a table named items that has the columns itemId (int), retailPrice(decimal(8,2), and title(varchar)

I'm trying to make a user defined function in mySQL that accepts an itemId as input and returns the retail price of that item.

But every time I try to run a select with it it returns the price for the itemId I select but lists every row in the item table. I want it to just return the 1 row relative to the itemId

so far I have this bit of code

```
CREATE FUNCTION itemPrice (itId DECIMAL(8,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
 declare rp decimal(8,2);
 select retailPrice into rp from item
 where itemId = itId
 return (rp);
END$$
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you calling your function?

Comment: select itemId, title, itemPrice(#)
    from item;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY

```
select itemId, title, itemPrice(#) 
from item  
where itemid = #
```

Comment: That works well, but Is there any way I can build that where into the function? So when I call the function it only returns one row. Because currently when I call it without the where clause it gives me the retailPrice for the itemId but it lists every item in the item table with the retailPrice for the one item I input into the function

Comment: not clear on what you asking, but what about just `SELECT itemPrice(#)` ??

Comment: As @JuanCarlosOropeza mentioned, call using 

SELECT itemPrice(#), if you want you can concatenate other values as the current will only return only the itemPrice.

Comment: Okay I apologize if I'm not explaining this well, but what I want to do is refine the function so that when I call it, I don't have to use a where statement to list only the itemId i put in the function input when I call it. because how the function is now when I call it, it lists this. https://app.box.com/s/iky5jcwacvq3gottvfe61ifhuuiqng4f

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of what you get when you run SELECT itemPrice(#)

Comment: Still not understand what you want. Your function return a single value that is OK. Your using in a select table of course will return multiple rows. So no, you cant change your function to return a single row if you are using it on a select. Unless you filter that select with a WHERE like i show you here.